# Control Tip Text on dual monitors?

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I have a small user community for an application that contains a lot of user forms and fields.
I have added ControlTipText on most of the fields as helper/reminder.
The problem occurs when the user form is opened/displayed on the secondary monitor, the yellow stuff
(ControlTipText) is popping up on the right edge of the primary monitor.
Not a huge issue, but annoying.
Anyone who has a fix for this?

Answer (score 1):

Same issue, resolved by:

Creating a label with a distinctive background colour positioned over the control that you want to write tip text for
Initialise the UF with the label visible = false, e.g. Userform1.label1.visible = false
use the "mousemove" event to write code to show the label
    Private Sub TextBox1_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer,  ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
label1.visible = true
'position label as desired
End Sub

use the click or mousemove event on the label this time to banish the tool tip. You will have lots of labels over controls in the VB editor.

As an alternative I creatie a label with an "Information" icon that is clickable to unhide the tooltip label rather than mousemove event sometimes

Answer (score 0):

As `ControlTipText` is a *property* of the `Text Box` it doesn't have any members which would allow you to adjust it's position.

[It seems like](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/1001374-positioning-controltiptext-with-dual-monitors-print.html) the only way the issue can be resolved is by viewing Excel on your primary monitor. If it's useful, you can force Excel to move to the primary monitor with something like this:

```
With Application
    .WindowState = xlNormal
    .Left = 0
    .Top = 0
    .WindowState = xlMaximized
End With
```

Comment: it is up to the user if they want to move excel to their secondary or not. but when they do and they open the userform, it too will open on the secondary, that's when the tooltip will open on the main monitor causing headaches.

Comment: @pokemon_Man Unfortunately it doesn't look like there's a nice solution - the code above does move Excel to the primary monitor, which means even if the user opened Excel on the secondary monitor it would be moved when they open your forms, for example. You could even add a warning to let them know it was happening so it wouldn't be such a shock.